# How can iI transfer EWS get item body to PST file via golang or other language but C#

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Now, I am trying to export email data. The data exported will be import to outlook to check locally but server.
I have read the doc [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange).
Can I transfer EWS data (export-item/get-item) to PST file using golang or cmd tools?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have success.The method LogonPstStore params Encryption should be 0 so that mac outlook can import it.
Golang code:

```js
func main() {
    ole.CoInitialize(0)
    session, err := oleutil.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    s, err := session.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // create a pst file
    p := `E:\go_project\src\github.com\outlook-ical-export\redemption\t22.pst`
    store, err := oleutil.CallMethod(s, "LogonPstStore", p, 1, "", "", 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(store, err)
        return
    }

    // get a folder object
    inbox, err := s.CallMethod("GetDefaultFolder", 6)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(inbox, err)
        return
    }

    stores := oleutil.MustGetProperty(s, "Stores").ToIDispatch()

    defaultStore := oleutil.MustGetProperty(stores, "DefaultStore").ToIDispatch()
    IPMRootFolder := oleutil.MustGetProperty(defaultStore, "IPMRootFolder").ToIDispatch()
    IPMFolders := oleutil.MustGetProperty(IPMRootFolder, "Folders").ToIDispatch()

    newFolder := oleutil.MustCallMethod(IPMFolders, "Add", "test22").ToIDispatch()
    newFolderItems := oleutil.MustGetProperty(newFolder, "Items").ToIDispatch()
    RDOMail, err := newFolderItems.CallMethod("Add", "IPM.Note")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(RDOMail, err)
        return
    }

  data := "base64"   
    ftsDataPath:= `E:\go_project\src\github.com\outlook-ical-export\redemption\test22.txt`

    d, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)

    err = ioutil.WriteFile(ftsDataPath, d, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = RDOMail.ToIDispatch().CallMethod("Import", ftsDataPath, 1034)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = RDOMail.ToIDispatch().CallMethod("Save")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = defaultStore.CallMethod("Remove")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    v, err := s.GetProperty("FastShutdownSupported")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if v.Value() != nil && v.Value().(bool){
        _, err = s.CallMethod("DoFastShutdown")
        if err != nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }else {
        _, err = s.CallMethod("Logoff")
        if err != nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not in EWS directly. You can export the MIME content using EWS and then import it into a PST file either using your own MIME parser, [IConverterSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iconvertersessioniunknown) built-in MIME converter (C++ or Delphi only, only works when tuning inside the outlook.exe process) or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author, use [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import(..., olRfc822)`).

Note however that MIME is not a high fidelity format, all MAPI-specific properties will be lost. Fast Transfer Stream format preserves all properties, but it is not documented. You can export the items using the `ExportItems` EWS request, and import them into a PST (or any other message) using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) and [RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import(..., olFTS)`. A PST file can be created using [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonPstStore`, you can then create folders ([RDOFolder](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`Folders.Add` starting with [RDOStore](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).`RootIPMFolder`) and messages (`RDOFolder.Items.Add`).

Comment: I have read the document of  Redemption and RDOMail,but found no method can be used in other language like golang or python.It is a tool installed on windows or be imported in C#.Can it be used in Golang and linux?

Comment: Redemption is Windows only and requires the MAPI system to be installed (which means Outlook must be installed). But you need Outlook to open PST files anyway. Redemption can be used from nay language that can use COM object (such as the Outlook Object Model) - Python can use Redemption for sure. I don't know much about Golang, but it looks like it can use COM too.

Comment: Yes,It is ok.But is there a free tool? The developer version will pop up a window.Thanks very much any way.

Comment: I am not aware of a free tool.

Comment: Hello.I have created a pst file.How can I deal items which exported by EWS ExportItems?Can you give me a demo code by any language?

Comment: If possible,can you give me a total demo usIng C# or VB or other? if we can finish our business,we will purchase it.

Comment: The key promeblem is how to put items expoted by ExportItems  into the pst file?

Comment: If using Redemption, call `RDOFolder.Items.Add` - that will give you a new `RDOMail` object. Call` RDOMail.Import(..., olFts)` and then `RDOMail.Save`

Comment: Item will be put in when I call  RDOFolder.Items.Add? ExportItems get a xml.When should I put it in?Will i put origin xml into RDOFolder.Items.Add?

Comment: No, as I mentioned before, you need to call `RDOMail.Import` to import the FTS data. Redemption expects the raw binary data - you will need to extract base64 encoded data from the `Data` XML node, convert it to binary, save as a file, and pass the file name to `RDOMail.Import`

Comment: There is a problem.After I creat a pst file using  RDOSession.LogonPstStore,the process not exit until so long time.And The pst file will be using until so long time.  How to solve it? When I import my data using RDOMail.Import, an error named "Expected a page break marker" occured.How to solve it?Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean your process cannot terminate? Or that the PST file will not get released? In the latter case, PST provider keeps the PST files open for 30 minutes after they were removed from the profile for performance reasons. As for the Import error, are you sure you converted the data from base64 to raw?

Comment: The former question:YES,cannot terminate and  the PST file will not get released.Can I close it manually?

Comment: There is another problem.When import the PST file into mac out look,it occured an error "file error"

Comment: Do you mean your process hangs? Which line of your code causes the hang? For the corrupted PST file, are any errors reported when you run scanpst.exe against it?

Comment: If you have a sample project that causes the hang, you can send it to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com.

Comment: Ok.Now the key question is when importing the PST file into mac out look,it occured an error "file error".How to solve it?is the err caused by no header writted into the file?

Comment: When I called store.remove,it exit at a short time(10s).But when i used scanpst.exe,it reported error as before.

Comment: Can you give me a total demo code.We will buy it.If the problem can not be solved, we will give up it.

Comment: I can give you a sample C# app, but you are using Go. Are you limited to using that particular language?

Comment: My program is testing.It runs good before.But now when I calling LogonPstStore,it hangs.What is the reason?Network?FireWall?Or the count of experience run out?

Comment: I sent the debug version of Redemption to you.