# When transfering EWS item by exporItem to pst using Redemption,I got a file.The file can not be imported in mac outlook

Tags: macos, encoding, outlook, character-encoding, outlook-redemption

It occured an error "file error".My code followed
When importing into windows,no error occured.But the detail is not like the detail by outlook.
When importing into mac,error named "file error" occured.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole/oleutil"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    ole.CoInitialize(0)
    session, err := oleutil.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    s, err := session.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // create a pst file
    p := `E:\go_project\src\github.com\outlook-ical-export\redemption\t21.pst`
    store, err := oleutil.CallMethod(s, "LogonPstStore", p, 1, "", "", 2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(store, err)
        return
    }

    // get a folder object
    inbox, err := s.CallMethod("GetDefaultFolder", 6)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(inbox, err)
        return
    }

    stores := oleutil.MustGetProperty(s, "Stores").ToIDispatch()

    defaultStore := oleutil.MustGetProperty(stores, "DefaultStore").ToIDispatch()
    IPMRootFolder := oleutil.MustGetProperty(defaultStore, "IPMRootFolder").ToIDispatch()
    IPMFolders := oleutil.MustGetProperty(IPMRootFolder, "Folders").ToIDispatch()

    newFolder := oleutil.MustCallMethod(IPMFolders, "Add", "test21").ToIDispatch()
    newFolderItems := oleutil.MustGetProperty(newFolder, "Items").ToIDispatch()
    RDOMail, err := newFolderItems.CallMethod("Add", "IPM.Note")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(RDOMail, err)
        return
    }
    data := "base64"
    ftsDataPath:= `E:\go_project\src\github.com\outlook-ical-export\redemption\test21.txt`

    d, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(ftsDataPath, d, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = RDOMail.ToIDispatch().CallMethod("Import", ftsDataPath, 1034)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = RDOMail.ToIDispatch().CallMethod("Save")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = defaultStore.CallMethod("Remove")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    v, err := s.GetProperty("FastShutdownSupported")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    if v.Value() != nil && v.Value().(bool){
        _, err = s.CallMethod("DoFastShutdown")
        if err != nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }else {
        _, err = s.CallMethod("Logoff")
        if err != nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: I have solve it.
Refering to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70872858/how-can-i-transfer-ews-get-item-body-to-pst-file-via-golang-or-other-language-bu/71220027#71220027)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in encoding which is not related to Redemption at all.

The `SaveAs` method of the `RDOMail` class saves the message to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. Try using it instead.